# Icon is not visible in container in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

Icon is not visible inside container
Can anyone do this?

```
body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      color: colorOfContainer,
                      cardChild: Column(
                        children: [
                          FaIcon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                            size: 80.0,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'MALE',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              color: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I tried changing container color, size & also i try by  removing expanded

Comment: Can you include `ReusableCard` and others data